# Tool for finding from which block Geth is in archive mode?

Tags: go-ethereum, tools, archive-node

e.g. I can run `geth` in archive mode after the 17.000.000 block. I know I can find a wallet address and run `getStorageAt` manually on multiple blocks to find if my node was archive or not.

But is there a tool used for this? Output of the command would be the exact block from which my node is in full archive mode.